# Working flow of Jasmine framework in protractor

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine

I am new to Angular js & Protractor. Though by doing some research, I found out that Jasmine is the default framework used by Protractor but unable to understand the working flow of jasmine. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You write your describe-function and write your test-cases inside the it-function calls. 
Inside the it-function-blocks you write your test-conditions like expect foo is true or something. 
Protractor integrates the jasmine workflow (function-calls and expectations) inside the webdriver workflow (serialising the promises in the webdriver query/controlflow).
Thats the simple short answer.